# Wordpress SEO remove "-" at the end of SEO title

Tags: wordpress, seo, title

I had try to looking for the code generate the SEO title in every posts to remove '-' at the end of title. Normally, when the title show on the browser, it already have '-' between title and browsers.

```
Ex: title - chrome, title - firefox, title -  safari
```

But for now, as i see it as:

```
title - - chrome, title - - firefox, title - - safari
```

It seems quite ugly in the title of posts. 
I had try to remove it in class-frontend.php, but it seems doesn't effect. So, how can i remove it? or it should be remove when get the title of a post and generate to put into SEO title fields in every posts

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1):

put below script after wp_head() function in header.php or at the end of the header.php

it will remove extra "-" from title tag.

```
<script>

var str = document.title;
var res = str.split(" ");
var final_res="";
var count=0;
for(i=0;i<res.length;i++)
{
    var n=final_res.indexOf("-");
    if(n==-1)
   {
     count=0;
   }
   else
   {
     count=1;
   }


   if(res[i]!="-" || count==0)
   {
     final_res=final_res+" "+res[i];
   }
   else
   {
     final_res=final_res;
   }    

}
document.title=final_res;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution : check and remove "-" of the title in class-frontend.php in WP SEO.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the plugin configuration is ok for titles, and if the issue cannot be solved there.

We can modify the SEO Title using the following filter in `functions.php` or in a functionality plugin:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', function( $title ) 
{
    $new_title = str_replace( '- -', '-', $title ); // Adjust to your liking
    return $new_title;
});
```